# pesky bug in JS tic tac toe game

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const winCombos = [
     [0, 1, 2],
     [3, 4, 5],
     [6, 7, 8],
     [0, 3, 6],
     [1, 4, 7],
     [2, 5, 8],
     [0, 4, 8],
     [6, 4, 2]
];

let playerTurn = 'X';

for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
     const cell = document.getElementById('c' + i);
     cell.addEventListener('click', startGame);
     function startGame() {
          cell.innerHTML = playerTurn;
          if(checkForWin()) {
               alert('game over');
          }
     }
}

function checkForWin() {
     for(let i = 0; i < winCombos.length; i++) {
          const c0 = document.getElementById('c' + winCombos[i][0]);
          const c1 = document.getElementById('c' + winCombos[i][1]);
          const c2 = document.getElementById('c' + winCombos[i][2]);
          if(c0.innerHTML===playerTurn&&
             c1.innerHTML===playerTurn&&
             c2.innerHTML===playerTurn) {
               return true;
          } else {
               return false;
          }
     }
}
```

```css
td {
 border:  2px solid #333;
 height:  100px;
 width:  100px;
 text-align:  center;
 vertical-align:  middle;
 font-family:  "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
 font-size:  70px;
 cursor: pointer;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -155px;
 top: 220px;
}

table tr:first-child td {
 border-top: 0;
}

table tr:last-child td {
 border-bottom: 0;
}

table tr td:first-child {
 border-left: 0;
}

table tr td:last-child {
 border-right: 0;
}

.endgame {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  top: 120px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>tic tac toe</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td class="cell" id="c0"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c1"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="cell" id="c3"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c4"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="cell" id="c6"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c7"></td>
   <td class="cell" id="c8"></td>
  </tr>
  <div class="endgame">
   <div class="text">Cant see this text</div>
  </div>
 </table>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey guys I'm trying to make a simple JS tic tac toe game. Right now all I want to do is line 3 'X's up and as soon as that 3rd X is placed to make a winning combination I want an alert message. But instead when you click to place the 3rd 'X' to win the game, the alert message shows up right away then the 3rd 'X' is displayed??? why is this, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important thing to understand here is javascript runs in a single threaded model. Now let's take a look at your code:

```
cell.addEventListener('click', startGame);
function startGame() {
     cell.innerHTML = playerTurn;
     if(checkForWin()) {
          alert('game over');
     }
}
```

In the click event handler, you do following things:

1. Update content of the cell
2. Check for Winning move
3. Display alert if last move was a winning move

From CPU's perspective all of this "actions" are done serially, so you expect content of the cell will be rendered first, right? However, that is not the case. When you set innerHTML of the cell, DOM will become dirty and changes will be rendered on next render thread cycle which will happen when your javascript thread becomes idle. However you still have actions 2 and 3 pending so they are executed first and then when javascript thread becomes idle, your rendering thread will take a front seat and update the screen.

I hope now you have a clear idea about how javascript work.

Now, to solve your issue you can set a minor timeout before displaying alert so that your page is updated before alert is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The `startGame` listener is running *synchronously*, right after the click has occured, and `alert` *blocks* the browser - it prevents further Javascript and re-rendering from occuring until the alert is dismissed. When the function runs, the browser hasn't had time to repaint yet.

You might use `requestAnimationFrame` to ensure that the `alert` is displayed only *after* the browser has finished re-rendering to show the new `x`:

```
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert('game over');
    });
  });
```

```js
const winCombos = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [6, 4, 2]
];

let playerTurn = 'X';

for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  const cell = document.getElementById('c' + i);
  cell.addEventListener('click', startGame);

  function startGame() {
    cell.innerHTML = playerTurn;
    if (checkForWin()) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          alert('game over');
        });
      });
    }
  }
}

function checkForWin() {
  for (let i = 0; i < winCombos.length; i++) {
    const c0 = document.getElementById('c' + winCombos[i][0]);
    const c1 = document.getElementById('c' + winCombos[i][1]);
    const c2 = document.getElementById('c' + winCombos[i][2]);
    if (c0.innerHTML === playerTurn &&
      c1.innerHTML === playerTurn &&
      c2.innerHTML === playerTurn) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid #333;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -155px;
  top: 220px;
}

table tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 0;
}

table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

table tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}

table tr td:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

.endgame {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  top: 120px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>tic tac toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell" id="c0"></td>
      <td class="cell" id="c1"></td>
      <td class="cell" id="c2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell" id="c3"></td>
      <td class="cell" id="c4"></td>
      <td class="cell" id="c5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell" id="c6"></td>
      <td class="cell" id="c7"></td>
      <td class="cell" id="c8"></td>
    </tr>
    <div class="endgame">
      <div class="text">Cant see this text</div>
    </div>
  </table>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Or, even better, use a proper modal instead. `alert`s and related blocking functions are very user-unfriendly.

Also note that function declarations are *hoisted* to the top of their containing function (or top level) - they shouldn't be inside a `for` block.

You can also reduce your `checkForWin` function down to three lines if you use array methods instead:

```js
const winCombos = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [6, 4, 2]
];

function startGame() {
  cell.innerHTML = playerTurn;
  if (checkForWin()) {
    document.querySelector('.endgame').style.display = 'block';
  }
}


let playerTurn = 'X';

for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  const cell = document.getElementById('c' + i);
  cell.addEventListener('click', startGame);

}

const checkForWin = () => winCombos.some((combo) => (
  combo.map(i => document.getElementById('c' + i))
    .every(cell => cell.textContent === playerTurn)
))
```

```css
td {
  border: 2px solid #333;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -155px;
  top: 220px;
}

table tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 0;
}

table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

table tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}

table tr td:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}

.endgame {
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  top: 120px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell" id="c0"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="c1"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="c2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell" id="c3"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="c4"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="c5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cell" id="c6"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="c7"></td>
    <td class="cell" id="c8"></td>
  </tr>
  <div class="endgame">
    <div class="text">Game is over</div>
  </div>
</table>
```